# Boost and Autoconf

Tags: linux, boost, autoconf

I am making a project that uses Autoconf. I have the following in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([boost/foreach.hpp], [],
    [AC_MSG_ERROR(You need the Boost libraries.)])
```

When I run `configure`, it says it cannot find this header file:

```
checking boost/foreach.hpp usability... no
checking boost/foreach.hpp presence... no
checking for boost/foreach.hpp... no
configure: error: You need the Boost libraries.
```

This is strange, because I have Boost. If I remove the check, the code compiles, and I have Boost installed:

```
$ find /usr/include -name foreach.hpp
/usr/include/boost/foreach.hpp
/usr/include/boost/test/utils/foreach.hpp
```

Note that I did exactly the same with SDL, and it works.

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([SDL/SDL.h], [],
    [AC_MSG_ERROR(You need the SDL development library.)])
```

...

```
checking SDL/SDL.h usability... yes
checking SDL/SDL.h presence... yes
checking for SDL/SDL.h... yes
```

Comment: Check config.log to see exactly why it failed.  academicRobot is probably correct that it is trying to compile with a C compiler.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AC_CHECK_HEADERS actually does a a compile check, not an existence check.  So you have to set C++ support for compilation tests in order for boost headers to compile (default is C, [docs here](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/autoconf/Language-Choice.html)):

```
AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([boost/foreach.hpp], [],
    [AC_MSG_ERROR(You need the Boost libraries.)])
AC_LANG_POP([C++])
```

Answer (score 9):

You may be interested in [github.com/tsuna/boost.m4](http://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4), which is a drop-in set of Autoconf macros for checking for Boost headers and libraries, as well as the minimum Boost version.

Answer (score 9):

There's also a collection of Boost autoconf macros at the [GNU Autoconf Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/).  You'll probably need at least [AX_BOOST_BASE](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_boost_base.html#ax_boost_base).  Other macros for the other Boost libs are there also.